# Как объединить столбцы с разных таблиц в SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных

Как мне объединит одинаковые столбцы в таблице 1 и таблицей 2  ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я пробою

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (users)
SELECT users
FROM table_1
```

но, он не объединяет, а вставляет после первой таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас в левой таблице занчение только 'test' ? тогда в правой просто update tab set users='test'. А если все таки разные значения то вам надо определиться сначала с тем, какое же значение из первой таблицы в какую конкретно запись второй таблицы должно попасть и написать соответствующие условия в `update ... join`. Обратите внимание, порядок строк в БД ни как не гарантирован, нельзя сказать "из первой записи в первую" потому что никакой "первой записи" не существует (пока не указан порядок сортировки)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.USERS = t2.USERS
```